# Can't redirect to new page Ajax beginform

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this Ajax.Beginform-code:

```
<script>
    function createsuccess(data) {
        if (data.RedirectUrl) {

            window.location.href = data.RedirectUrl;
        }
    }
</script>
     @using (Ajax.BeginForm("New", "Profile", null, new AjaxOptions()
            {
                HttpMethod = "Post",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                OnSuccess = "createsuccess"
            }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

               //HTML-code
            }
```

Here Is my New action in my Profile controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult New(Profile model)
{
    model.UserId = UserId;

    if (_profileService.CreateProfile(model) > 0)
    {
        var encryptedProfileId = Encryption.Protect(model.ProfileId.ToString(), UserId.ToString());
        Response.Cookies["ProfileId"].Value = encryptedProfileId;

        return Json(new { RedirectUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Welcome") });
    }
    return View();
}
```

When I run this and tries to create a new profile, I am not redirect. Instead, I am redirected back to my New-page with the following JSON displayed:

[image]

Why am I not redirected?

Comment: Because you have not included `jquery.unobtrusive.ajax.js` (bit why in the world are you using ajax is you want to redirect)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I have included It. But It seems not to be loaded. And I don't know why.

Comment: Stephen is right. You are adding a lot of complexity here with AJAX and getting no benefit from it. AJAX is specifically *for* calling the server while keeping the page from redirecting. You should eliminate it by using `Html.BeginForm` in your view and return `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Welcome");` from your action method instead of JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Add "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" to your page. If you're using the "bundling" feature in System.Web.Optimization, one easy way would be to add it to the jQuery bundle:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery")
    .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js")
    .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"));
```

You can also just add a `<script>` tag that points to the script.